# Closing active tab via keyboard in Firefox for Linux

Tags: firefox, opensuse-12.2

I'm familiar with FF for Windows: CTRL+F4 closes the currently active tab.

On FF 16.0.2 shipped with openSUSE 12.2 that doesn't work, I have to click on the X.

How can I close a tab via keyboard in FF16 for Linux'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CTRL+W`.

I use this on Windows too.
Alternatively, you can install the "keyconfig" addon. I'm not sure if it still works due to Firefox's fast development process. See: http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi

Comment: Tested it on nightly, the addon still works perfectly. You can just add a new hotkey. :)